# Remove element from ArrayCollection on OneToMany wont delete it on persist()?

Tags: doctrine-orm

In a Zend Framework 2 project, we got two Doctrine 2 entities and we would like to remove an element from a collection allready saved in the database...

***So we have a first entity named FormGroupConstraint :***

```
/**
 * FormGroupConstraint
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="form_group_constraint")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Application\Dao\FormGroupConstraintDao")
 */
class FormGroupConstraint {

    /**
     * @var integer 
     * 
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
     protected $id;

    /**
     * @param \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Application\Entity\FormQuestionConstraint", mappedBy="groupConstraint", fetch="EAGER", cascade={"persist", "merge", "refresh", "remove"})
     */
     protected $constraints;

     public function __construct() 
          $this->constraints = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
     }

     /**
     * @param \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection $constraints
     */
     public function addConstraints($constraints) {
        foreach ($constraints as $constraint) {
            $this->constraints->add($constraint);
        }
        return $this->constraints;
    }
    /**
     * @param \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection $constraints
     */
     public function removeConstraints($constraintsToRemove) {
            foreach ($constraintsToRemove as $key => $constraintToRemove) {
                $this->constraints->removeElement($constraintToRemove);
            }
            return $this->constraints;
     }
}
```

***And the sub entity named FormQuestionConstraint :***

```
/**
 * FormQuestionConstraint
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="form_question_constraint")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Application\Dao\FormQuestionConstraintDao")
 */
class FormQuestionConstraint
{
    /**
    * @var integer
    *
    * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
    * @ORM\Id
    * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
    */
    protected $id;

    /**
    * @var \Application\Entity\FormGroupConstraint
    *
    * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Application\Entity\FormGroupConstraint", cascade=   {"persist", "merge", "refresh", "remove"})
    * @ORM\JoinColumns({
    *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="form_group_constraint_id", referencedColumnName="id")
    * })
    */
    protected $groupConstraint;
}
```

So if we try to create, persist, flush a FormGroupConstraint entity, no problem,
but when we want to remove an element of $constraints ArrayCollection, nothing happens...

We are using doctrine-orm-module for zend 2 installed with composer.phar in dev-master...

***Here is an example of what we are trying to do :***

```
$constraint = $this->findConstraintByGroup(1);

$formGroupConstraint = $this->_em->findOneById(1);

$formGroupConstraint->getConstraints()->removeElement($constraint);
$this->_em->persist($formGroupConstraint);
$this->_em->flush();
```

No error, but no delete or remove...
And if we var_dump() the getConstraints() before persist(), actually the element is still in the ArrayCollection...

Could anyone explain us how we could do that or why the element is not removed ?

Comment: A great explanation of the topic is [here](https://gist.github.com/pylebecq/f844d1f6860241d8b025).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the reference is held on `FormQuestionConstraint` you need to do:

```
$this->_em->remove($constraint);
$this->_em->flush();
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but the problem is, when we try to loop over the ArrayCollection to see wich entities are removed, there isn't any changes between the database and the current ArrayCollection...

Any removeElement($constraint) is useless ???

Why this method don't do anything on the ArrayCollection?

(Hibernate list or other ORM Collection container could work like this...)

Comment: there's no change to the ``ArrayCollection`` even after calling ``flush()``?? try calling ``$this->_em->flush()`` if not.

Comment: What we would like to do is : 

**1 : load $formGroupConstraint**
**2 : remove elements by calling  $formGroupConstraint->getConstraints()->removeElement($constraint);** 
**3 : at the end, do $this->_em->persist($formGroupConstraint); $this->_em->flush();**.   

But nothing is removed from the collection nor from the database. Is this process is possible ?

Comment: from [doctrine association docs](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/unitofwork-associations.html): "Doctrine will *only* check the owning side of an association for changes." Because the reference is held on ``FormQuestionConstraint``, you need to remove it as indicated in my answer.

Answer (score 33):

Maybe a bit late but try adding `orphanRemoval=true` to the inverse side (OneToMany) of relationship

```
@ORM\OneToMany(
    targetEntity="Application\Entity\FormQuestionConstraint",
    mappedBy="groupConstraint",
    cascade={"persist", "remove"},
    orphanRemoval=true
)
```

Comment: This is a better solution than the first one, no need for extra code.

Comment: In the case of YAML for other users (like me): orphanRemoval:true in the "left" field for the OneToMany relation.

Comment: Why is it so hard to find anything for symfony or doctrine heh, thanks it's great answer!

Comment: Be careful, ManyToOne doesn't have attribute orphanRemoval, this has to be on OneToMany side

Answer (score 7):

You could add `orphanRemoval=true` on the `OneToMany` side of the relation, for instance like this:

```
@ORM\OneToMany(
    targetEntity="Application\Entity\FormQuestionConstraint",
    mappedBy="groupConstraint",
    cascade={"all"},
    orphanRemoval=true
)
```

The reason for this behaviour is that the entity is removed from the ArrayCollection, but the collection's contents are only determined by the child entity's foreign key pointing to the parent entity.

When doctrine looks up the parent entity's children for the next time, it's still there and will be shown in the next request again, when the ArrayCollection is fetched from the database again.

If `orphanRemoval` is set to `true`, such child entities will be removed upon `persist()`.